# Multiply all values in hash together in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, key-value, multiplication

I would like to multiply all the values of a hash together without having to call the specific elements. E.g. I *DON'T* want to do `$hash{'kv1'} * $hash{'kv2'} * $hash{'kv3'}` because I won't know the number of elements in the hash to do this.

I'm guessing there is a simple and efficient function to do this, maybe using `each` or something, but I can't find any examples to follow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start at 1 (since 1 multiplied by anything is what you multiple it by), then loop over the values of the hash and multiple the current total value by the value from the hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.12;
my %hash = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4 );
my $value = 1;
$value = $value * $_ foreach values %hash;
say $value;
```

Comment: shortened a bit using `$value *= $_`

Answer (score 9):

This is what [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util)'s **reduce** is for:

```
use List::Util 'reduce';

my %hash = (foo => 3, bar => 7, baz => 2);

say reduce { our $a * our $b } values %hash;
```

Output:

> 42

Answer (score 4):

I would iterate over `keys %hash` like this:

```
my $prod = 1;
$prod *= $hash{$_} for keys %hash;
```

Comment: `values` should be okay as I don't need to worry about order of elements

Comment: It was more a reflection on my own coding style compared with the other answers than an indication then I'm smarter than the others...

Answer (score 2):

will this not do?

```
my $m = 1;
for (values %my_hash) {
    $m *= $_;
}
```

Comment: Because you can't assign a value to the `m`